# How to define a custom function of an instance using setattr

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add a method to a class dynamically, but I keep running into an error where `self` is not passed to a the new function. For instance:

```py
class Dummy():
    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi")


def new_method(self):
    print("bye")


dummy = Dummy()
setattr(dummy, "say_bye", new_method)

dummy.say_bye()
```

results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    dummy.say_bye()
TypeError: new_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType) feature:

```
from types import MethodType

class Dummy():
    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi")


def new_method(self):
    print("bye")


dummy = Dummy()
dummy.say_bye = MethodType(new_method, dummy)

dummy.say_bye()   # bye
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the function `new_method` as an attribute of the `dummy` object.

If you do `print(dummy.__dict__)` you'll see something like this:

```
{'say_bye': <function new_method at 0x7fcd949af668>}
```

This means that your `dummy` object has the function `new_method` as an attribute, so when you do `dummy.say_bye()`, you're calling the function you have as an attribute without any argument.

It is not a function of the `Dummy` class, it is just a function that your `dummy` object has as an attribute.

You can achieve the functionality you are looking for using RomanPerekhrest's answer.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!